# How to format JSP code in Eclipse with Java SWT?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I'm generating a plugin in Eclipse. My plugin generates source JSP code in an open Editor so I would like to format the whole code, just as if I pressed Ctrl+Shift+F.

I try to do that with Eclipse JDT:

```
Properties prefs = new Properties();
        prefs.setProperty(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, CompilerOptions.VERSION_1_8);
        prefs.setProperty(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, CompilerOptions.VERSION_1_8);
        prefs.setProperty(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, CompilerOptions.VERSION_1_8);
        CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(prefs);
        String texto2 = texto;
        IDocument dc = new Document(texto2);
        //ICompilationUnit cu = (ICompilationUnit)JavaCore.create(texto_editor);

        TextEdit edit_formatear =
                  formatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, 
                          texto2, 0, texto2.length(), 0, null);

        if(edit_formatear!=null){
            edit_formatear.apply(dc);
            System.out.println("Edit: "+dc.get());
        }

    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I think this code only work with java code...

Any idea?

Comment: SWT is GUI code, it is nothing to do with code formatting.

Comment: Cannot I use JDT o something similar?

Comment: JSP support in Eclipse is part of [Eclipse WTP](https://eclipse.org/webtools/). That _might_ provide something.